# UnsolicitedResponse at /auth/acs/

Tags: python, xml, django, saml-2.0, okta

I am trying to configure my python based app(SP) to auth with okta. when i directly hit the url of the app. It properly authenticates the user and give the response. but when I click the app icon on the okta wall it throws the exception "UnsolicitedResponse". can any one has any clue why this is happening?

I have configure my IDP like this
[image]

hear is the error log

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/auth/acs/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     UnsolicitedResponse
Exception Value:    

Unsolicited response: None

Exception Location:     /nfs/wfc-zit-fil-002/home/v-sohilc/git/module/Services/saml-app/eggs/pysaml2-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/saml2/response.py in loads, line 517
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for no reply I found one answer for myself,

the saml 1 use to respond with UnsolicitedResponse. i just need to set boolean at the sp side saying allow_UnsolicitedResponse = true in the setting.py (django).

Comment: then please suggest 1

Comment: I am sorry, now that I know more about SAML I totally agree with your solution. My bad 